# memory access violation using std::map as local member

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a memory access violation error on the line `m_Lights=tmp;` during the call of the method `v_init()` in `Algo::Init()`. Shouldn't map `m_Lights` be created at the instantiation of `m_LightsManager`?  Why do I have this error?

```
class LightManager 
 {
 private:
   std::map<sint32,Light> m_Lights;
  public:
   LightManager (void);
  ~LightManager (void);
  void v_init();
 };

LightManager ::LightManager (void)
{

}



LightManager ::~LightManager (void)
{
}

void LightManager ::v_init()
 {
  Light tL;
  std::memset(&tL,0,sizeof(Light));
  std::map<sint32,Light> tmp;
  tmp.insert(std::pair<sint32,Light> (-1,tL));
  m_Lights=tmp;
 }

class Algo 
{
 private:    
  LightsManager m_LightsManager;
 ....
 public:
 Algo();
 void Init();
 };

  Algo::Algo()
  {
  Init();
   }


 void Algo::Init()
 {

   m_LightsManager.v_init();

 }
```

Comment: The code would be a lot easier to read if it was indented properly...

Comment: What is `Light` and why are you doing this `std::memset(&tL,0,sizeof(Light));`?

Comment: OT What's the reason for `v_init` ? Use the constructor!

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2):

If `Light` is not [trivially-copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) then

```
std::memset(&tL,0,sizeof(Light));
```

is **undefined behavior**. This is likely the cause of your error.

Comment: ...and even if it was trivially-copyable that line is highly suspicous and probably shouldnt be there in the first place

Comment: I added because I had already the error thinking that it may come from the object tL,

Comment: @Bil: we can't really help you properly without a [MCVE], all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Vittorios answer: Do all the initialization in `Light`s constructor, instead of relying on an external `memset` call. And don't use `std::memset` in C++ to initialize all member variables of an object in one statement, do it explicitely for every variable (usually using a simple assignment; in C++11 you can do that even in the declaration/header, where it IMHO belongs).

Reason: `Light` may be derived, and the base class(es) define their own data, which you overwrite by recklessly nulling the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error, the problem came from a wrong declared pointer in other part of the soft that overlaped with the memory space where the object m_LightsManager where initiated ,

Comment: See, that's why you're supposed to give a [mcve] instead of just dropping a blob of code you **assume** the problem must be hidden.